# C# LINQ to XML : how to join Xml Data

Tags: c#, xml, linq, join

Given two XML files like these:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer CustomerID="alc">Alice</Customer>
</Customer>
```

and

```
<Orders>
  <Order OrderID="001" CID="alc">apple</Order>
</Orders>
```

Now I need to join these two XML files and create a new one by using inner join:

```
<Result>
  <Join>
     <Customer CustomerID="alc">Alice</Customer>
     <Order OrderID="001" CID="alc">apple</Order>
  </Join>
</Result>
```

I have this query:

```
var result = new XElement("Result",
     from customer in XElement.Load("Customers.xml").Elements("Customer")
        join order in XElement.Load("Orders.xml").Elements("Order")
        on
            (string)customer.Attribute("CustomerID")
        equals
            (string)order.Attribute("CID")
        select new XElement("Join",
               new XElement("Customer", (string)customer.Element("Customer"),
               new XAttribute("CustomerID", (string)customer.Attribute("CustomerID"))),

               new XElement("Order", (string)order.Element("Order"),
               new XAttribute("OrderID", (string)order.Attribute("OrderID")),
               new XAttribute("CID", (string)order.Attribute("CID")))));
result.Save("result.xml");
```

With this I can't get the data "Alice" and "apple". The result is like this:

```
<Result>
  <Join>
    <Customer CustomerID="alc" />
    <Order OrderID="001" CID="alc" />
  </Join>
</Result>
```

I think maybe the `(string)customer.Element("Customer")` and the `(string)order.Element("Order")` have some problems and I don't know how to modify these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [cast an element to a `string`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx) to get its text value:

```
    select new XElement("Join",
           new XElement("Customer", (string)customer,
           new XAttribute("CustomerID", (string)customer.Attribute("CustomerID"))),

           new XElement("Order", (string)order,
           new XAttribute("OrderID", (string)order.Attribute("OrderID")),
           new XAttribute("CID", (string)order.Attribute("CID")))));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the `customer` and `order` variables upon creation of `Join` element, instead of creating new `XElement`s for the same :

```
select new XElement("Join", customer, order);
```

**[working demo example :](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HgfEFh)**

```
var customersxml = @"<Customers>
  <Customer CustomerID='alc'>Alice</Customer>
</Customers>";
var ordersxml = @"<Orders>
<Order OrderID='001' CID='alc'>apple</Order>
</Orders>";

var result = new XElement("Result",
                          from customer in XElement.Parse(customersxml).Elements("Customer")
                          join order in XElement.Parse(ordersxml).Elements("Order")
                          on (string)customer.Attribute("CustomerID") equals (string)order.Attribute("CID")
                          select new XElement("Join", customer, order));
Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
```

**output :**

```
<Result>
  <Join>
    <Customer CustomerID="alc">Alice</Customer>
    <Order OrderID="001" CID="alc">apple</Order>
  </Join>
</Result>
```